# comparing a DateTime in CakePHP

Tags: datetime, cakephp

I have a query in CakePHPthat has a stored "datetime" field called `DropIn.drop_in_time`.  I would like to only "find" entries where the `DropIn.drop_in_time is > NOW()` but am having trouble getting it to do that.

The condition `DropIn.drop_in_time >' => 'NOW()` didn't get the right results in the query below. Is there a better way to do it?

```
$requests = $this->DropIn->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('DropIn.drop_in_time >' => 'NOW()', 'or' => array(array('DropIn.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')), array('DropIn.id' => $drop_in_ids))),
            'order'=>array('DropIn.created'=>'DESC')));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you separate the value as `'DropIn.drop_in_time' => 'NOW()'`, `'NOW()'` is taken to mean the literal value string `"NOW()"`. Just write it as one SQL fragment instead: `'DropIn.drop_in_time > NOW()'`. Alternatively, use `'DropIn.drop_in_time >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

Comment: thank you so much! That advice was great. I knew it was some silly syntax issue

Comment: you can also do 'Model.date > ' => (object)'NOW()' iirc

Comment: @deceze you are a boss.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to put DB expressions into CakePHP finds, you can use the expression method:

```
'DropIn.drop_in_time.' => $db->expression('CURDATE()');
```

However this is kinda of losing the point of the database abstraction that a framework provides, so do as suggested by deceze and compare it with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 0):

use DboSource::expression('NOW') instead of only NOW()